# Download data from online database in python script

Tags: python

I am trying to download data from [UniProt](https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/?query=*&fil=organism%3A%22Homo%20sapiens%20%28Human%29%20%5B9606%5D%22%20AND%20reviewed%3Ayes) using Python from within a script. If you follow the previous link, you will see a Download button, and then the option of choosing the format of the data. I would like to download the Excel format, compressed. Is there a way to do this within a script?

Comment: If you want to summon Darth Vader riding Donald Trump to fight Velociraptors with lasers strapped to their heads, there's _definitely_ a way to do that in Python. What code do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily see the URL for that if you monitor it in the Firefox "netowork" tab or equivalent. For this page it seems to be `https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/?query=*&format=xlsx&force=true&columns=id,entry%20name,reviewed,protein%20names,genes,organism,length&fil=organism:%22Homo%20sapiens%20(Human)%20[9606]%22%20AND%20reviewed:yes&compress=yes`. You should be able to download it using `requests` or any similar lib.

Example:

```
import requests

url = "https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/?query=*&format=xlsx&force=true&columns=id,entry%20name,reviewed,protein%20names,genes,organism,length&fil=organism:%22Homo%20sapiens%20(Human)%20[9606]%22%20AND%20reviewed:yes&compress=yes"
with open("downloaded.xlsx.gz", "wb") as target:
    target.write(requests.get(url).content)
```